# PHP - Select an entire array containing a particular value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a following array:

```
array(4){ 
[0]=> array(4){ 
["id"]=> int(1) 
["item_name"]=> string(8) "Oilspill" 
["requests_count"]=> int(0) 
["item_information"]=> string(21) "Just some spilled oil"
} 
[1]=> array(4){ 
["id"]=> int(2) 
["item_name"]=> string(3) "Fan" 
["requests_count"]=> int(0) 
["item_information"]=> string(12) "Standart fan" 
}
[2]=> array(4){ 
["id"]=> int(3) 
["item_name"]=> string(12) "Green candle" 
["requests_count"]=> int(0) 
["item_information"]=> string(16) "Smells like moss"
}
[3]=> array(4){ 
["id"]=> int(4) 
["item_name"]=> string(8) "Yin Yang" 
["requests_count"]=> int(0) 
["item_information"]=> string(22) "Ancient Chinese symbol"
}
```

Is it possible to select an entire array that contains the id value I'm looking for?

For example: I want an item with id=2, the output would be:

```
[1]=> array(4){ 
["id"]=> int(2) 
["item_name"]=> string(3) "Fan" 
["requests_count"]=> int(0) 
["item_information"]=> string(12) "Standart fan" 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use a `foreach` loop that stops when it finds the id value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Loop through all of your rows, then look for the id value of 2.

```
//outer loop
foreach($array as $row){

    //inner condition
    if($row['id'] == 2){
        //do what you need with this value
    } 
}
//...
```

Comment: Yeah but how do I get the entire array that contains id of 2?

Comment: Yeah that worked. I wasn't on a computer much sry :D. Thanks alot.